# Expressing a subtraction from a Hermitian outer products' main diagonal in terms of the original vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, trace

Consider a vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}$, and its complex conjugate transpose $\mathbf{x}^H$. Computing the outer product of both vectors results the matrix $\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^H$.

Now I would like to subtract$\mathbf{\Phi}$ from the identity matrix multiplied with the trace $\text{tr}(\cdot)$ of $\mathbf{\Phi}$:

$\mathbf{\Psi} = \text{tr}(\mathbf{\Phi})\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{\Phi} $.

For my application, it would be preferable if an explicit computation of $\mathbf{\Phi}$ could be avoided.

The trace can be expressed in terms of $\mathbf{x}$ (I think):

$ \text{tr}(\mathbf{\Phi}) = \sum_i \mathbf{x}_i^2$.

My questions are

- Is my reformulation for the trace correct?
- Can $\mathbf{\Psi}$ be expressed in a way that does not require me to compute $\mathbf{\Phi}$?

I am also interested in any rules or concepts that cover or have a name for this specific problem, as I do not have a strong math background.

Comment: Is computing an orthonormal basis containing $\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}$ within your possibilities?

Comment: I think so, even though I'll have to read up on how to do that.

Comment: Just so we're clear, the naive approach is complexity $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Yes, I am not necessarily looking for an approach that has lower complexity right now.

Comment: Your formula for $\Psi$ expresses the negative of the thing sentence describing it.

Comment: Thank you for telling me! I updated the question.